# Links continuously repeating after puting this code

Tags: php, regex, while-loop, preg-replace

Am having problem with this particular code. When I put it in my wp single.php, it worked, but continued to repeat the link till infinity.

Eg:

```
https://www.example.com/hello-world/
https://www.example.com/hello-world/
https://www.example.com/hello-world/
https://www.example.com/hello-world/ etc
```

Can someone help me make the link appear once instead of repeating multiple times.

Here is the code:

```
$string='that html code with links';
// while matches found
while(preg_match('/<a class="click" href="([^"]*)">/', $string, $matches)){
    // print captured group that's actually the url your searching for
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Although i got the code from somewhere (I didn't write it myself) and it seems to work. But the outcome which is a link continues to repeat till infinity.

Your help is highly apprecited!

Comment: For what reason do you use a `while` loop? Note that the behavior of `preg_match` is totally different of `RegExp.prototype.exec()` in Javascript.

Comment: Without the while loop, the code does not pull any link at all. It seems to be a NO DO WITHOUT inclusion.

Comment: If I understand well, your goal is to display all links that match your pattern. In this case you use the wrong function. Take a look at the PHP manual about `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`. As an aside instead of using a direct string approach (with regex or not), when you have to deal with a structured language like html, it's better (and more robust, in other words it's the way to go) to use an html parser (`DOMDocument`, `DOMXPath` are classes you have to learn).

Comment: In the whole content having other links and html attributes, my goal is to display just one link which has "click" as its class name.

Comment: I would have loved to use html parser, but I do not understand its usage for now.

Comment: You can find many examples of `DOMDocument` and `XPath` in this site (use tags to reduce the search results), but it's better to try one or more tutorials about them. (it isn't slower than asking a question in a forum, and gives more benefits).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe this would temporarily  solve our problem here:

```
$string='that html code with links';
if(preg_match('/<a class="click" href="([^"]*)">.*/s', $string, $matches)){
    // print captured group that's actually the url your searching for
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdzdAN/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/tdzdAN/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.